# Create a record and an associated record in one go

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

**The Problem:**

Imagine I have two associated models, `Library` which *has many* `Book`s:

```
var Library = sequelize.define('Library', {
    title: Sequelize.STRING,
    description: Sequelize.TEXT,
    address: Sequelize.STRING
});
var Book = sequelize.define('Book', {
    title: Sequelize.STRING,
    description: Sequelize.TEXT,
    publish_date: Sequelize.DATE
});
Library.hasMany(Book);
```

Now, in order to create a `Library` and a single associated `Book`, I do:

```
Library.create({
    name: 'Roan Library',
    address: '123 Any St'
}).then(function (library) {
    Book.create({
        title: 'Reading with Time',
        description: 'A fun jaunt in reading',
        libraryId: library.id
    });
});
```

**The Question:**

Is it possible to create a `Library` and a `Book` instance in one go - in a *single `create()` call*?

Something like (more like a pseudo-code):

```
Library.create({
    name: 'Roan Library',
    address: '123 Any St',
    books: [
        {
            title: 'Reading with Time',
            description: 'A fun jaunt in reading',
            libraryId: library.id
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Without having the ID of the parent element the relationship is broken. So you have to create the rows separately. The best thing that you can do is extending the model by adding a method to the `classMethods` property,  the method should do this behind the scene. Something like `Library.createAndThenCreateARelatedBook(...)` :)

Comment: Correction: related/parent row and not "parent element" (this has nothing to do with DOM, of course).

Comment: @Vohuman I'm quite new to sequelize but I'm afraid you are right - it makes sense in general. Feel free to post it as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: I'm new to sequelize too. I have only used the library in a project last year. I use knex. The sequelize has many features but it has bad documentations (dynamically generated).   It seems `create` accepts an `include` option when an instance is created but I'm not sure how it works.

Comment: @Vohuman yeah, the documentation definitely needs to be improved. And, here on SO, I don't see sequelize gets enough attention.

Comment: @Vohuman by the way, it is actually appeared to be supported by sequelize, what a surprise - see the answer.

Comment: I told you there is an `include` option :) I'm glad that after 9 days your question has an answer and sorry that I couldn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired behavior can be achieved by adding the include option to the create parameters like so:

```
Library.create({
    name: 'Roan Library',
    address: '123 Any St',
    Books: [
        {
            title: 'Reading with Time',
            description: 'A fun jaunt in reading'
        }
    ]
}, {
    include : [Book]
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have problems to get it to work - `library` is of course undefined and I have to omit the `libraryId` key. When I do this, it is only creating a `Library` record ignoring the `books`. Can you provide a reproducible sample?

Comment: Hi @alecxe,
Thanks for your reply. Right, you don't need the library.id there because there is no library instance yet.
Also, the property should be Books instead of books because the model itself is capitalized also (Book instead of book). Just tested it on my local machine and it works.

Comment: Oh wow, yeah, it works. I wonder why does not sequelize have things like this documented (maybe I overlooked the docs though). Thanks a lot.