# Create model with its association in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using [`sequelize`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/) as my `nodejs` web app ORM.
I have 2 models, `Offer` and `Game`. There is a 1:1 association between them, and I am considering how to implement it.
First, I tried using `Offer.belongsTo(Game)` so that the `GameId` resides in the `Offer` model. When I create an `Offer`, I want that the `Game` to be created as well.

I have set the association as follows:

```
Offer.belongsTo(models.Game, {
      foreignKey: {
        allowNull: false
      }
    })
```

So that the `GameId` will never be null. In `sequelize` [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#creating-elements-of-a-belongsto-or-hasone-association), it is noted that I could create the `Game` together with the `Offer` like this:

```
models.Offer.create({Game:{"name":"The Last of Us", "platform":"PC"}},{include:[models.Game]});
```

But I'm getting:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: null value in column "GameId" violates not-null constraint
```

How can I create an `Offer` and a `Game` in 1 action using the not null constraint?

EDIT:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Game = sequelize.define("Game", {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    platform: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM('PC', 'PS4', 'PS3', 'XB1', 'XB360'),
      allowNull: false
    },
    cover: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        notEmpty: true
      }
    }
  }, {
    updatedAt: false,
    createdAt: false
  });

  return Game;
};

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Offer = sequelize.define("Offer", {
    price: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      validate: {
        max: 999,
        min: 0
      }
    },
    exchange: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: true,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    updatedAt: false,
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Offer.belongsTo(models.Game, {
          foreignKey: {
            allowNull: false
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });

  return Offer;
};
```

Comment: Not directly related, but, more like just FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37892699/create-a-record-and-an-associated-record-in-one-go.

Comment: Can you post the definition of models?

Comment: @Shaharyar Added the models.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put anything for `Offer` object. You're just passing `Game` object.

```
models.Offer.create({
    //set fields for 'Offer'
    Game:{"name":"The Last of Us", "platform":"PC"}
    },
    {include:[models.Game]}
);
```

Also, you just have to define `foreignKey` while setting associations. Constraint definition resides in model:

```
Offer.belongsTo(models.Game, {
      foreignKey: 'GameId'
    });
```

Comment: There are a few fields to `Offer` which I did omit. There is no need to set the name of the foreign key, since it is the default name.